# C# - Executar Procedure Oracle e em seguida realizar select na tabela de sessão criada

Tags: c#, oracle, select, procedure

Olá, estou tentando realizar a o seguinte. Tenho uma procedure que realiza um select e insere os dados em uma tabela que só existe naquela sessão. Eu preciso executar essa procedure e em seguida consultar a tabela que ela gravou os registros.

O comando utilizado é o seguinte:

```
--Executo a procedure
Exec sp_procedure(Parametros);

--Consulto Procedure
Select * from tb_resultado_procedure
```

Quando eu realizo esse grupo de comandos no sqlDeveloper funciona normalmente e trás o retorno porém quando executo no C# ao realizar a tabela a mesma vem vazia.

Segue código utilizado no C#.

```
oraCON = new OracleConnection(Stringconexao);
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = oraCON;
oraCON.Open(); 

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "sp_procedure";

cmd.Parameters.Add("parametro", OracleType.VarChar).Value = "Valor";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "select * from tb_resultado_procedure;";

OracleDataAdapter orada = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
orada.Fill(dsoPN, "resul");

grdResultado.DataSource = dsoPN;

grdResultado.Refresh();

oraCON.Close();
```

A procedure executa normal porém a tabela vem com os dados vazios no C# enquanto no SqlDeveloper ela vem preenchida.

Como executar a procedure e em seguida consultar a tabela no C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era a procedure que eu estava chamando que estava com ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS foi necessário colocar a opção ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS

Segue referência utilizada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017641/duration-of-data-in-a-global-temporary-table